# Retrieving Xpath from SOAP Message

Tags: java, xml, soap

I want to retrieve all the xpaths from soap message at run time.

For example, if I have a soap message like

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Bodyxmlns:ns1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/TestAppln_jws/TestEmail/TestEmail">
 <ns1:process>
          <ns1:To></ns1:To>
          <ns1:Subject></ns1:Subject>
          <ns1:Body></ns1:Body>
        </ns1:process>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

then the possible xpaths from this soap message are

1. `/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:process/ns1:To`
2. `/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:process/ns1:Subject`
3. `/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:process/ns1:Body`

How can i retrive those with java?

Answer (score 2):

Use the [XPath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html) type with a [NamespaceContext](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/NamespaceContext.html).

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("foo", "http://xmlns.oracle.com/TestAppln_jws/TestEmail/TestEmail");
NamespaceContext context = ...; //TODO: context from map
XPath xpath = ...; //TODO: create instance from factory
xpath.setNamespaceContext(context);

Document doc = ...; //TODO: parse XML
String toValue = xpath.evaluate("//foo:To", doc);
```

The double forward slash makes this expression match the first `To` element in the `http://xmlns.oracle.com/TestAppln_jws/TestEmail/TestEmail` in the given node. It does not matter that I used `foo` instead of `ns1`; the prefix mapping needs to match the one in the XPath expression, not the one in the document.

*You can find further examples in [Java: using XPath with namespaces and implementing NamespaceContext](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/05/java-using-xpath-with-namespaces-and.html). You can find further examples of working with SOAP [here](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2011/04/java-jax-ws-web-services-and-clients.html#ws_dynamic).*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
string[] paths;
function RecurseThroughRequest(string request, string[] paths, string currentPath)
{
    Nodes[] nodes = getNodesAtPath(request, currentPath); 
    //getNodesAtPath is an assumed function which returns a set of 
    //Node objects representing all the nodes that are children at the current path

    foreach(Node n in nodes)
    {
        if(!n.hasChildren())
        {
            paths.Add(currentPath + "/" + n.Name);
        }
        else
        {
            RecurseThroughRequest(paths, currentPath + "/" + n.Name);
        }

    }
}
```

And then call the function with something like this:

```
string[] paths = new string[];
RecurseThroughRequest(request, paths, "/");
```

Of course that won't work out of the gates, but I think the theory is there.